# SSIS Bulk Insert where fields contain commas?

Tags: sql, ssis

My bulk insert in SSIS is failing when a field contains a comma character. My flat file source is tab delimited and there are many instances in which a text field will contain commas. For example, a UserComment may have a comma. This causes the bulk insert to fail.

How can I tell SSIS to ignore the commas? I thought it would happen automatically since the row delimiter is {CR}{LF} and the column delimiter is "Tab". Why does it bark at the comma? Also please note that I am NOT currently using a format file.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the error I get in SSIS:
*Error: 0xC002F304 at Bulk Insert Task, Bulk Insert Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 183, column 5 (EmailAddress).Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 182, column 5 (EmailAddress).Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 181, column 5 (EmailAddress).".
Task failed: Bulk Insert Task*

It seems to fail on record 131988 which is why I think it's because of the "something,something" email with no space. Many records before 131988 come across fine.

```
131988  01  MEMPHIS, TN     someone@somewhere.com  
131988  02  NORTH LITTLE ROCK, AR       someone@somewhere.com,someone1@somewhere1.com  
131988  03  HOUSTON, TX     someone@somewhere.com,someone1@somewhere1.com
```

Comment: Is it expecting text qualification, e.g., double quote marks or something around your text fields?  That would be separate from the question of whether the delimiter is a tab or a comma.

Comment: See update. It should not be expecting text qualification, I didn't specify anywhere anything related to that or using double quotes around anything.

Comment: The three records with the email,email (that could be the problem). Also exceed the destination column's length. I would think a truncate error would be thrown instead of an invalid character one but I will change in source and test to determine if it is in fact the length or the comma.

Comment: The error "type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage" is misleading. I was trying to write data to a field where the length of the source was greater than the length of the destination. When I fixed the length issue it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked!  I should have guessed from the "type mismatch" part.  I went down the primrose path of "invalid character" instead.  Win some, lose some ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage" is a misleading error message. The source table's field length exceeded the destination table's specified length and thus the error. After adjusting lengths, everything worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the comma or the @ sign is being called an "invalid character".

I see there are two tabs in the input record just before the field that contains the email addresses, so that email address column would be the fifth column.  But when the error message refers to "column 5" it's presumably using zero-based indexing, so the email column is only index 4.  Is there tab and another column?  Maybe the invalid character is there.

I suspect there is a invisible bad character embedded in whatever column is causing the error.  I often pick up bad characters when cutting and pasting out of email address lines, so that's a likely suspect.

Run the failing line by itself to make sure it still fails.

Then copy it into, say, Notepad, and do a "Save As" with the Encoding set to ANSI.  (It may complain at that point if there's a bad character.)  Use the "Save As" file as the new import file.  At this point you should be able to be reasonably confident that "what you see is what you get", and that there are no invisible characters embedded in the import file.

If this turns out to be the problem, you'll need some way to verify that future import files are clean, or else handle them somehow during the import process.

(I presume you've checked the destination column length is okay.  That would definitely be a showstopper.)

Comment: Thanks but it turned out to be a length issue. The error message was misleading. See my comments above. I up-voted for the useful comment though.